# Modify code to take textContent from li instead of thumbnail img src?

Tags: javascript, css

I found (and tweaked) the code below that was designed for switching the larger img src with the src of thumbnails in a list, but I'm not sure how to adjust it to use something like https://picsum.photos/id/CLICKED_LI_textContent/200/200 as the URL instead of pulling from a thumbnail's src.

For some more context here's the original post in which I was looking into this
[How can I change img src from list of (non-image) items?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70055321/how-can-i-change-img-src-from-list-of-non-image-items/70055686)

I haven't taken any JS classes, so I'm not sure how every component of the script works. I'm more comfortable with pure HTML and CSS, but think JS is the answer for making this work more smoothly.

(I did add the jquery script src to the document for this)

Sorry the code is a little ugly, I would have added the script and style tags and such but I ran out of time while posting this

```
$("#list li").click(function(e) {
  // if i use this getting undefined
  // var src = $(this).attr("src"); 
  // so i use this method
  var target = e.target;
  var src = target.src;
  console.log(src);
  $("#display").fadeOut(function() {
    $(this).on('load', function() {
      $(this).fadeIn();
    });

    $(this).attr("src", src);
  });
  //record which thumb was clicked
  $("#list li").removeClass("active"); //remove class
  $(this).addClass("active"); //apply class to selected thumb
});

//move next
$("#left-arrow").click(function() {
  if ($("#list li.active").next("#list li").length > 0) {
    $("#list li.active").next().children( 'img' ).trigger("click");
  } else {
    $("#list li:first > img").trigger("click"); //go to first
  }
  return false;
});

//move previous 
$("#right-arrow").click(function() {
  if ($("#list li.active").prev("#list li").length > 0) {
    $("#list li.active").prev().children( 'img' ).trigger("click");
  } else {
    $("#list li:last > img").trigger("click"); //go to end
  }
  return false;
});

//click the first thumb to begin
$("#list li:first > img").trigger("click");
    .container {
  display: flex;
}

.active {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #990000;
}

.list {
  width: 200px;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 0.25rem;
}

list > li * {
  /* so only the li tag can be event.target, and none of it's children */
  pointer-events: none;
}

.display {
  max-width: 500px;
  max-height: 500px;
}
    <div class="container">
  <div class="list">
<ul id="list">
    <li>237</li>
    <li>240</li>
    <li>100</li>
    <li>301</li>
</ul>
<a href="#" id="left-arrow">$larr;</a> &nbsp; <a href="#" id="right-arrow">$rarr;</a>
  </div>
  <div class="show">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/237/200/200" class="display" id="display">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is there a reason you introduced jquery? My suggestion would be that as a beginner with JavaScript you stick to that for now especially as the original answer you were given was in JS and although it had a couple of errors it basically works.

Comment: `$(this).attr("src", src);` is what changes the `<img>`'s `src` attribute. You want to change the value of `var src =` if you want it to be the `textContent` of the clicked `<li>`, then it would be`var src = target.textContent`, but I'm not sure this is what you want.

Comment: A Haworth: I moved to jQuery bc I found an example close to what I'm hoping to achieve, and it seemed like it would be easier to change the way the img src is built in this code than to figure out adding previous/next buttons to the pure js code, but I could be super wrong.

Comment: Kaiido: I think that's getting close to what I want, though. I wonder if I could do something like var src = "../images/" + target.textContent

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a pure javascript solution. The only difference is that it lacks the fading between the images.

I tried to write the code as pedagogic as possible, using variables as explanations. The code goes more with your original thread, where you had a bunch of images with different file endings. I gave the image an `alt` attribute, so you can see the change.

A short explanation:

1. Use an array for the images.
2. Create your list through javascript, using the array.
3. Add click listeners to your `#list`, where you read the `.textContent`. I added `pointer-events: none;` to any children to the `li` tags so they don't trigger the click listener.
4. Add click listeners to your prev/next buttons, where you check which index that the currently visible image has in the array (from 0 to 3 in `imageArr`) and then adds +1 och -1 to that index.

[edit] Added code for updating the CSS.

```js
const listEl = document.getElementById('list');
const imgElement = document.querySelector('.right > img');

let imageArr = ["237.jpg", "240.gif", "100.jpeg", "301.png"];   // 1
let currentImage = '';

document.getElementById('next').addEventListener('click', () => shiftImage(1));
document.getElementById('prev').addEventListener('click', () => shiftImage(-1));
listEl.addEventListener('click', displayImage);

function updateImage(imageName) {
  const subfolder = 'images/';

  changeActive(imageName, currentImage);  /* ADDED in EDIT */
  currentImage = imageName;

  imgElement.src = subfolder + imageName;
  imgElement.alt = imageName;
}

/* ADDED in EDIT */
function changeActive(newImage, oldImage) {
  if (oldImage) {
    let oldIndex = imageArr.indexOf(oldImage);
    toggleActiveClass(oldIndex);
  }
  
  let currentIndex = imageArr.indexOf(newImage);  
  toggleActiveClass(currentIndex);
}

/* ADDED in EDIT */
function toggleActiveClass(imageIndex) {
  let liElements = listEl.childNodes;
  liElements[imageIndex].classList.toggle('active');
}

function shiftImage(direction) {
  let currentIndex = imageArr.indexOf(currentImage);
  let newIndex = currentIndex + direction;
  
  if      (newIndex < 0)                { newIndex = imageArr.length - 1; }
  else if (newIndex >= imageArr.length) { newIndex = 0; }

  let newImageName = imageArr[newIndex];
  
  updateImage(newImageName);
}

function displayImage(event) {
  let liElement = event.target;
  updateImage(liElement.textContent);
}

function constructImageLinks() {    // 2
  let htmlOutput = '';
  
  for (let imageSrc of imageArr) {
    htmlOutput += `<li>${imageSrc}</li>`;
  }
  
  listEl.innerHTML = htmlOutput;
}

constructImageLinks();
updateImage(imageArr[0]);
```

```css
section {
  display: flex;
}

section ul {
  margin-top: 0px;
}

section > .left li {
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 0.25rem;
}

section > .left li.active {
  background-color: pink;
}

section > .left li > * {
  pointer-events: none;
}

section > div {
  padding: 1rem;
}

section > .right > img {
  width: 200px;
  border: 1px solid;
  padding: 0.5rem;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div class="left">
    <ul id="list"></ul>

    <button id="prev">Previous</button>
    <button id="next">Next</button>
  </div>

  <div class="right">
    <img>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: This works beautifully, thank you. Sorry it took me so long to follow up on this. I added an event listener to change the active class on click. I'm curious though if there's a pure JS way to make the active class on each li element correspond with the previous/next button clicks (in addition to changing the display image, changing the highlighted li element). I've only found jQuery solutions. If you have an idea of a pure JS solution for that I'd be very appreciative!

Comment: @kherezae No worries. I updated the snippet, adding two methods that toggles the class "active".

Comment: You are a true hero, thank you. I've learned a ton from this. I think it's about time I take some sort of self-paced class though so I can fill in the many gaps in my understanding. (: Thank you again!

Comment: You can read through, and do the examples, in W3Schools in about a week. That would cover the basic and intermediate topics: https://www.w3schools.com/js/default.asp

Answer (score 0):

[JSFiddle - Link](https://jsfiddle.net/gmq7z3pd/2/)

#### HTML

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="list">
<ul id="list">
    <li>237</li>
    <li>240</li>
    <li>100</li>
    <li>301</li>
</ul>
<a href="#" id="left-arrow">$larr;</a> &nbsp; <a href="#" id="right-arrow">$rarr;</a>
  </div>
  <div class="show">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/240/200/200" class="display" id="display">
  </div>
</div>
```

#### Javascript

```js
// HELPER FUNCTIONS
function getImageURL(id, width=200, height=200){
    return "https://picsum.photos/id/"+ id + "/" + width + "/" + height;
}

function removeActive(){
    let lis = $('#list li');
  for(let i=0;i<lis.length;i++){
    $(lis[i]).removeClass('active');
  }
}

// HANDLE EVENTS

$(document).on('click', "#list li", async (e)=>{
    await $('#display').fadeOut();    
    removeActive();
        let li = $(e.target);
    li.addClass('active');
        let image_id = parseInt($(e.target).html());
    let image_url = getImageURL(image_id);
    $('#display').attr('src', image_url);
    await $('#display').fadeIn();
});

//move next
$(document).on('click', "#left-arrow", (e)=>{
    // Handler Here
});

//move previous 
$(document).on('click', "#right-arrow", (e)=>{
    // Handler Here
});
```

#### CSS

```css
.active {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #990000;
}

.list {
  width: 200px;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 0.25rem;
}

list > li * {
  /* so only the li tag can be event.target, and none of it's children */
  pointer-events: none;
}

.display {
  max-width: 500px;
  max-height: 500px;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
}
```